# LImit access to ribbon bar in dotnetnuke

Tags: security, module, dotnetnuke, portal

I have a dnn site that allows users to have child portals.  The child portals are either basic or advanced.  The advanced portals is basically unrestricted.  However the basic portals should be restricted to only being able to change the content provided to them but not being able to add any pages or modules.  Is that possible?  Is there a security module that will aid in that?

Answer (score 1):

Your description of basic portal security is possible to implement in DNN's role based access control.

The role assigned to the users:

- should **not** have page-level edit
  permissions
- should have edit
  permissions to selected modules

The problem is how to conveniently assign these permissions to new pages.
I recommend creating template pages first with the correct permissions, and then copying new pages from these templates. It is also possible to make a helper application for this copying. DNN API and the IPortable interface help here, but my experience is that with 3rd party modules you'll often need to implement the copy functionality yourself.

You can hide the control panel (ribbon bar) from Module Editors who are not Page Editors. This can be done from the Admin - Site Settings:

[image]